# CGAffineTransform rotation and setting the angle

Tags: swift, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

Is there an issue with the code below? I want to rotate my video90 degrees but whenever I try it the rotation returns a black screen.

```
let degrees : Double = 90; //the value in degrees
let rotate: CGAffineTransform = new.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180) ))
```

To test that the actual video is there, I have tried with the following and it does show on screen but obviously no rotation.

```
new.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(0) ))
```

Comment: what are `new` and `concatenating`? how is video created?

Answer (score 0):

This might be to do with the order in which you are applying the transforms. The results are different. If `new` is a translation. Then `new.concatenating(...)` will translate the rotation. This maybe not what you want. If you do this:

```
let rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))
new = rotation.concatenating(new)
```

This will rotate the translation, which might give you what you want.